# Limit max value of SQL calc

Tags: sql

Im currently working on a sql database that carries out several calculations based on external data.

Basically I have a field called 'Runhrs' and i take the max and min values of a specific day or a range of days.

The calculation will sometimes return (for example) 26 hours but as we know its not possible to have more than 24 hors in a day. The Calculation is correct but the data itself seems to have the errors but nothing can be done about the datas errors.

Therefore how do i limit the max value? The SQL statement is as shown:

```
    SELECT MAX(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho))) - MIN(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho))) AS RUNHO, CONVERT(VARCHAR,TIME_STAMP,103) AS TIME_STAMP 
FROM HL_LOGS 
WHERE TIME_STAMP BETWEEN @BEGIN AND @END AND ID_LOCATION = @ID 
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR,TIME_STAMP,103), CONVERT(VARCHAR,TIME_STAMP,111) 
ORDER BY CONVERT(VARCHAR,TIME_STAMP,111)
```

Thanks in advance,
Neil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a CASE clause:

```
SELECT CASE when MAX(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho))) -
                 MIN(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho))) > 24
            then 24
            else MAX(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho))) -
                 MIN(CONVERT(FLOAT,ISNULL(Runhrs,Runho))) 
       END AS RUNHO,
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** : @Mark Bannister is right. It actually does **not** work at all. See his answer.

If I understand correctly, just embed you `MAX` in a `MIN` call, like:

```
SELECT MIN(24, MAX(...))
...
```